# ios access user entered value in xib

Tags: ios, xib

I have a xib file that I am calling from one of my view controller implementation file. Following is the code that I am using to instantiate and push the view controller onto the navigation stack :-

```
upsertView=[[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"InsertView" owner:self options:NULL] lastObject];
UIViewController *vc=[[UIViewController alloc] init];
vc.view=upsertView;
[self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:NO];
```

The xib view contains three text files where the user can enter his values and do a save. This save is connected to a action in the same controller implementation file (from where I am calling xib). Here is the action :-

```
-(void) saveValues
{
    UIViewController *vc=[[self.navigationController viewControllers] lastObject];
    NSString *valID = ((UITextField *)[vc.view viewWithTag:23]).text;
    NSLog(@"%@",valID);
}
```

Can you please let me know if the above is the best way to get a user entered value from a xib?

Comment: Is the above method working?

Comment: yes. The above is a subset of the whole code. However, it is printing out the value of the valID

Comment: In general your code is ok. You can create weak outlets in viewController for textFields and read from them directly in your saving method - it will make code cleaner

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couple of suggestions

Just to be on the safer side, instead of directly taking the lastObject from the array returned from function `loadNibNamed:owner:options:`, its better to iterate through the array for your view and then pick the right one.

Using `viewWithTag` is also not recommended. I personally have had some bad experiences with that. Apple internally maintains tags for some of the views. So if your tags overlap with that, it can be very confusing to resolve.

Instead you can maintain IBOutlets for the textfields in your controller using which you can easily get the data.